# spring-cloud-task how to pass messages or flag between two apps

Tags: spring-cloud-task

I have already made a Ingestion job using spring batch which reads xml file and ingest into AEM and its working fine.
Now, I am trying to convert this apps into Spring cloud Task. I want to split this apps into 4 different part which is individual apps. I need to connect them into spring cloud data workflow and pass some data and flags based on that next flow will be execute.
Is it possible on spring cloud Task? if yes then how can I bind them? please provide some programming tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

In the recent [1.2.0.RELEASE](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/announcing-spring-cloud-data-flow-1-2), we have released a new feature called the ["Composed Tasks"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-tasks). With this, you could define a directed graph that's made of several `spring-cloud-task` (SCT) applications.

Each step in your flow can be an independent SCT application, which you can develop, test, and CI/CD in isolation. Once you're ready to orchestrate them as a composed graph, you'd then register and use them in the specially designed [composed-task DSL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_composed_task_dsl) or the [drag & drop GUI](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_creating_composed_task_definitions).

Checkout this [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KT_4kVcyfRA) for more details.

Comment: How can I pass data between those tasks which are part of the composed task?

Comment: It is a smell to share data between standalone Task Apps since they have to have separated responsibilities (in a pure terms); that's why we don't do anything out-of-the-box. At the same time, it also seems legit to make decisions on an App based on upstream step’s outcome (not just exit code), a computed result perhaps. To accomplish that, you can choose to handle the outcome through custom solutions. An independent data store or message brokers are few options.