# Passing data between tasks in a Spring Cloud Composed Task

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have been working with Spring Cloud DataFlow and I have created my Composed Task which involves 3 Tasks.

My question is: **Is possible to share information between those tasks? What would be a good pattern to do this?**

I know that Spring Dataflow executes composed tasks as Spring Batch Jobs, so I was thinking that might be feasible share information using the `Context`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As responded in the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44303954/spring-cloud-task-how-to-pass-messages-or-flag-between-two-apps/44316482?noredirect=1#comment89746359_44316482), we don't provide out-of-the-box opinions because of the said reason.

However, if you have a requirement for it, you could use a shared database or a pub/sub broker for sharing information.